# How to preload fragment before it shows in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'd like to have similar function to ViewPager.
It preloads the fragments so when I swipe it, it shows smoothly the fragments.

Here is some detail for my app.
It pulls data from api when fragment is created(I call api in OnCreateView method), so once api call is complete, it shows all data. During call the api, it shows turning wheel.
Data contains Image and some Text.
I used Glide to show image. so it takes more time to show user.

I created swipe gesture so user can explore the fragments with swipe.
User should always wait for while to see the data because it calls api when it's shown.

Reverse swipe is perfect because it's already loaded.

Can I preload fragments to make same with reverse swipe? Or do I need to use ViewPager?
I think that it's also not perfect smooth even though I use ViewPager...

I want to show the data without waiting.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by. 'preload fragment' ?!, check [Fragment life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle), if you don't want your fragment to load data , then fetch the data outside fragment and then send them to the fragment

Comment: I mean creating view of fragment before showing.

Comment: @Passionate.C  If you know the number of page to be loaded before api call. You can just create views and use with recycler view .

Comment: I will need to preload 1~2 fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use ViewPager and it seems to work good.
I showed the loading overlay during call the web api.

Please give me the solution if anyone knows how to preload the fragment.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simple example of how you could achieve what you want and you need to fill out the lisview or data of the Page, you need in each of them in a single Asyntask.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentViewsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentsTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentViewsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentViewsList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentViewsList.add(fragment);
        fragmentsTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentsTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use the widgest android in this case you want to perform, this serial operation use FragmentPagerAdapter and perform a single service to fill the data of each of your.

Greetings.

Comment: Widgest Android? Can you give me more detail?

Comment: El perdón es widgets.

Comment: you mean ViewPager?

Comment: The operation of ViewPager is that it is loading one to the right of the selected position